# Edge swipe in fullscreen WPF app

Tags: wpf, touch, fullscreen, swipe

I have a Windows 10 fullscreen WPF application running on a touchscreen. Basically i just want to get some touchevents when i'm using edge swipe from bottom (swiping outside the screen into the screen from the taskbar direction). The application doesnt get any touch events (TouchDown, TouchUp, TouchMove) when i'm swiping vertical up, but fires all events when i am edge swiping vertical down.

I already disabled the Win 10 edge swipe functions and moved the taskbar / hide the taskbar. Is it not possible to recognize a edge swipe from bottom in WPF?